# How to do basic auth from frontend to backend and make browser remember the Authorization headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I have a backend written in Spring boot.
The authentication type is basic auth.
I have no problems authenticating with the backend.

If doing it from chrome, I get a basic auth dialog, I fill in my credentials and login.
After that I am logged in, I can refresh the window, go to other backend-endpoints and chrome remembers my login. It automatically sends the Authorization-headers every time.

But having the basic auth dialog popup is not very pretty so when logging in from my React  frontend (created with Vite) I have made a custom login which sends the Authorization: Basic xxxx header to the server.

To omit the basic auth dialog I added the header:
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

And sure, I can login, but only once.
Next time it fetches something from the backend I am not authenticated anymore.
Chrome does not send the Authorization headers every time like it does when using the basic auth dialog.

I have also played around with credentials: 'same-origin' but to no success.
In react/vite I am proxying my calls to the backend so CORS should not play a role here.
I have tried this both during development with localhost but also deployed it to a real server with a dns-name.

How can I make chrome remember my credentials?

Comment: Perhaps this was never meant to work. Anyway, I found a way around the problem. By implementing some sort of JWT solution.

Comment: _"To omit the basic auth dialog I added the header: X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"_ - meaning, your server did _not_ initially respond with 401 and a `WWW-Authenticate` header? Then Chrome has no reason to _recognize_ this as a protected realm to begin with, I suppose.